# 5–6,5 метра или метров (при интервале)?

Tags: число

Когда речь идет об отдельном дробном числительном, то существительным управляет дробь. А как быть с интервалом? Сохраняется ли тогда единственное число?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хороший вопрос на самом деле. Дело в том, что нет правил ***произношения*** интервалов с дробями.

А тут еще это половинка... Если её произнести как "шесть с половиной", то метров, а если "шесть и пять десятых", то метра. Без интервала второй вариант правильнее безусловно, ибо цифрами записано. Так что не будь интервала, было бы "6,5 метра". А вот когда есть интервал...

Наверное, все-таки надо полагать, что там проговаривается или подразумевается тире. А значит и ориентироваться надо на последнее число, которое имеет "пять десятых".

А значит, и все вместе будет ***"5-6,5 метра"***. Не уверен наверняка, что меня не поправят, но и не вижу, как тут еще можно рассуждать. Разве что в каком справочнике по-иному написано, но это будет трудно объяснимо.